# Junit test case fails with Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, lazy-loading

I am upgrading Hibernate from `5.1.17` to `5.4.11`. I am getting `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` while running `Junit` on collection whose fetch type is `LAZY`. I am trying to find different ways to make it work and run it in transaction(still facing some issues). Before that I would like to know what is changed after `5.1.17` which is causing this issue because earlier `Junit` test cases were working perfectly fine.

So what are the things changed related to lazy loading after `5.1.17`?

Comment: Could you please show your unit test.

Comment: I could not find the actual reason but in my Junit test case, one context file is being loaded to disable async job launcher. If I remove then Junit test case is passing.

Comment: Plz refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405357/org-springframework-dao-optimisticlockingfailureexception-with-hibernate-upgrade/61495179#61495179 , if anyone looking for the solution and same solution works for this.

Answer (score 0):

Many things changed, so it's hard to say. What I suggest is, start upgrading your hibernate by updating 1 minor version at a time (according to https://semver.org).

Once you pinpoint which minor version is causing a problem, check:

https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try adding this line to your test method:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
```

At least, this resolve my problem.