# org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException with hibernate upgrade

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-batch

I have upgraded Hibernate to `5.2.3` then I am getting `org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException` with spring batch job.

Spring job is to read data from file and process which will create flow chart kind of thing and related relations will be stored in db.

Before upgrade everything was working fine. What is the reason for this?

`Spring Batch version: 3.0.10.RELEASE`

It is happening when I got runtime exception(component already exists) then hibernate rollbacks the transaction but spring batch job should continue but it is throwing below error.

```
org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=0 with wrong version (1), where current version is 2
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcStepExecutionDao.updateStepExecution(JdbcStepExecutionDao.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:3.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:191) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:3.0.10.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy207.update(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:456) [spring-batch-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:3.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) [spring-batch-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:3.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) [spring-tx-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272) [spring-batch-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:3.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) [spring-batch-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:3.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:3.0.10.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_221]
14:52:18,095 ERROR [TaskletStep] JobRepository failure forcing rollback
```

Comment: From which version of Hibernate are you upgrading? Have you upgraded Spring Batch as well from a previous version or it is the same 3.0.10 before and after the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to set this property to resolve this issue

`hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction=true`

For more details:
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2/migration-guide.adoc#misc

Refer below link to view what changed over the releases
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/changelog.txt